# Drupal issue accessing custom content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm having an issue where a certain content type is not accessible by standard user accounts and anon users. The content type is Page (not the Drupal one but one I created). It contains nothing special, just static text.

When I try and view a page I see the title displayed but below that, the html from the tpl isn't included. So the issue is NOT that I get an access denied page. (The text is displayed in box with rounded corners top and bottom. The top ones are there but not the bottom ones, that's how I know the HTML isn't all being displayed)

This account can access all other content. In Permissions, access content is checked of course and I could find no entries that would determine simple viewing of a specific content type.

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you looked in the logs for anything suspicious?

Comment: Yeah, nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: What type did you give the new content type? Maybe you have a naming clash with Drupals default page type. You can give identical names, but the types need to be unique for the theming system to work, as the selection of preprocess functions, templates and other hooks depend on it.

Comment: Also, do you use CCK fields with your new content type? If so, recheck your permissions, as CCK fields have their own view and edit settings.

Comment: Just discovered there were indeed permission for CCK fields set, and then I read your comment.

One remaining issue: these roles can not access webforms (title & text displayed fine but the form isnt), but I can not find any entry in the Permissions for View Webforms. Do you know what entry I should be looking for?

Comment: Same for comment forms, these are not accessible for anon users.

Comment: Henrik Opel, post this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: As for Comment settings/permissions, there are general permission settings under `admin/user/permissions#module-comment`, but also some content type specific settings on the content type configuration form (collapsed fieldset 'Comment settings').  
I did not use Webforms yet, so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CCK fields with your new content type, you should recheck your permissions. CCK fields have their own view and edit permissions and will default to the most restrictive permissions by default.

(Note: Comment turned into answer)